# Set "secure" attribute for Flask cookies

Tags: python, flask

I am running a Flask app using uWSGI and Nginx. I want make it compliant with PCI DSS. Running the scan gives the error `Cookie Does Not Contain The "secure" Attribute`. How do I set the secure attribute for cookies in Flask?

I have added the following line in my Nginx file but it didn't work.

```
proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure;";
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The secure flag for Flask's session cookie can be enabled in the Flask [configuration](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE).

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

To set it for other cookies, pass the `secure` flag to [`response.set_cookie`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/dev/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.set_cookie).

```
response = app.make_response('<p>Hello, World!</p>')
response.set_cookie('name', 'World', secure=True)
```