# How to set an HTTPONLY cookie in Flask

Tags: python, flask, cookies, cookie-httponly

I read [Set "secure" attribute for Flask cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218195/set-secure-attribute-for-flask-cookies), but it's for setting secure cookies, but I'm trying to set HTTPONLY cookies. They both are kind-of-secure cookies, but differ in specs ([read more](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-cookies-httponly-secure-flags/)).

The cookie needs to be protected because it is about users' logging in information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check `set_cookie()` ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie)) under Flask APIs. It provides options for setting a HTTPONLY cookie using its `httponly` option. For example, the following code will set a HTTPONLY cookie:

`set_cookie("name", value = "value", httponly = True)`

Answer (score 6):

Flask provides a configuration value [`SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY) which controls whether cookies are set to be http only. By default, however, it is set to `True`, so unless it's explicitly set to `False`, cookies will be http only.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me where can I found documentation about all of the flask env variables? It was quite frustrating for me not to find a good docs or find only explanation of a basic vars. Thanks

Comment: @Dmitry on the same page as the link, all the environment variables are under the heading Builtin Configuration Values (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#builtin-configuration-values)

Comment: Thank you. I also found this [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#builtin-configuration-values) for 2.0.x version of flask.